# Applescript is unable to recognise path after importing foundation framework

Tags: applescript

I am able to show custom icon in AppleScript using below code

```
set iconPath to "/Users/dutt/myFolder/AppIcon.icns" as POSIX file
set theContent to " hi"
display dialog theContent with icon file iconPath with title "Hello" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button "Ok"
```

When I import foundation using below code, it is throwing error file doesnot contain icon

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions
set iconPath to "/Users/dutt/myFolder/AppIcon.icns" as POSIX file
    set theContent to " hi"
    display dialog theContent with icon file iconPath with title "Hello" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button "Ok"
```

I believe it is related to path issue, apple script is not able to get the icon path after using foundation framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use relative HFS paths, `path to home folder` points to the home folder of the current user.

This avoids the POSIX path - POSIX file - alias dance and works with and without `Foundation`

```
set iconPath to alias ((path to home folder as text) & "myFolder:AppIcon.icns")
set theContent to " hi"
display dialog theContent with icon iconPath with title "Hello" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button "Ok"
```

Note the missing `file` keyword after `with icon`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the way file references are resolved once you start implementing Objective-C frameworks into your AppleScript.

The solution is to build your file references using coercions.  So, change:

```
icon file iconPath
```

to:

```
icon (iconPath as alias)
```

Or it might even be necessary to change:

```
set iconPath to "/Users/dutt/myFolder/AppIcon.icns" as POSIX file
```

to:

```
set iconPath to "/Users/dutt/myFolder/AppIcon.icns"
```

then build the file reference in your `display dialog` command like this:

```
icon (iconPath as POSIX file as alias)
```